# best framework on gae(python) ,like jquery on javascript ? has it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, frameworks

i want to find a framework to make my work simple on gae ,

has it ?

thanks

i found  one, but not very good http://code.google.com/p/appengine-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of frameworks you can use on App Engine - both those custom designed for it, and those that are general purpose and work fine on App Engine. If you've used a Python framework in the past, some small amount of searching will tell you if it will work on App Engine with or without modifications. Common frameworks that do work on App Engine include Django, web2py and Pylons.

There's a fairly comprehensive list or open source tools [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/web/google-app-engine-open-source-projects).